# Which device are supported for unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am very new with unity. When I'm trying o run the project after the following the document,  it does not run `force close with hardware is not supported.`

> Simple blue screen with camera focus show at run in unity but in
>   device it can't.

In emulator it shows error like:

```
08-02 12:29:47.672: ERROR/libEGL(305): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
```

In device it shows:

```
Insatisfylinked
```

What should I do? Is there some device compatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this link](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Android-Devices%20That%20Have%20Been%20Tested.html) for a list of devices that have been tested with Unity.

According to [this post](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/74331-Unity-builds-for-Android-Emulator) (in which the author had the same problem as you) it is possible to get Unity running on the Android emulator, but performance is very poor.

Answer (score 1):

Unity CAN run on an emulator (use emulator mode when compiling) it just runs slow. On my phone (HTC legend, which is listed as incompatible), it runs slow and there's no sound, but it does work.

I think it's because for some odd reason or another, certain manufacturers didn't choose to support OpenGL on certain models.

Answer (score 0):

WIndows 8 and WIndows 8 phone will be supported when released as well!